# Meaning of "gnaw at"?

Tags: meaning

According to dictionary.com,
Gnaw means

> to bite (at) or chew (upon) constantly so as to wear away little by little

or

> to cause constant distress or anxiety (to)

In this case, in this sentence,

"*Four-eyes is just a small-fry who **gnaws at** tactics. He has no chance of winning against someone who can both strategize and fight*", what is the meaning of "**gnaws at**" in this context?

Comment: It is a rather idiosyncratic metaphorical usage.  One might expect to find "nibbles at" rather than "gnaws at" there, literally to "take tiny bites of something, as a mouse or a minnow does" with the figurative meaning "lacking prowess and thus having to rely (timidly) upon cunning".

Comment: Dogs gnaw on bones. To gnaw means to chew on something without eating it all at once. To keep biting it. Nibbles is something else. Dogs gnaw on bones and people can have anxiety gnawing on them. Idea? The person becomes the bone....

Comment: @Lambie: I very well know the difference between "nibbling" and "gnawing". I would venture to say that the author of the sentence didn't. "Fry" are fish, after all, and fish do not gnaw.

Comment: This is "literature". I see nothing wrong with gnaws at tactics and I most certainly do not think nibble at would be in the same semantic field. The idea here is that four-eyes does not make effective use of tactics.

Comment: http://worldtrigger.wikia.com/wiki/Masataka_Ninomiya

Comment: I wonder what exactly the character said in Japanese. (^_^)

Comment: Looks like the original is あのメガネは戦術をかじっただけの雑魚だ 戦術と戦闘どっちもいける”奴には勝てない.

Comment: Literally "Glasses (guy) is a small fish who only nibbles away at tactics, etc."  I think "gnaws" is a mistranslation of the metaphor.

Comment: *Gnaws at* sounds rather strange in English and doesn't make sense.  It's just a mistranslation of Japanese *kajiru* ([sense 2 here](http://www.excite.co.jp/world/j_dictionary/ITEM-DJR_kaziru_-010/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%98%E3%83%BB%E3%82%8B%E9%BD%A7%E3%82%8B/?itemid=DJR_kaziru_-010&title=%E3%81%8B%E3%81%98%E3%83%BB%E3%82%8B%E9%BD%A7%E3%82%8B)), meaning something like "dabble in; have learned just a bit of; know only a bit about/of; have picked up just a little bit of".  Judging by the sentence you've quoted, the translation you're reading is likely to be full of errors.

Answer (score 2):

I see this is a translation from a Japanese manga?  Looking at the original sentence, I would have translated it as "nibbles away at tactics" or "nibbles at the edges of tactics" instead of "gnaws at".

Either way it's a Japanese metaphor which does not have an exact equivalent in English.  A more interpretive translation is:

> "Four-eyes" (literally "Glasses" in Japanese) is a small-minded person who *plays at* tactics but has no hope to win against someone who can both fight and strategize.

Answer (score 1):

If you've ever seen a dog **gnawing** at a bone, he looks like he is trying to eat it, but is incapable of doing so and is possibly struggling, but might be enjoying it.  A kind of futility.

In your quote from the *World Trigger* manga series, *Masataka Ninomiya* compares *Osamu Mikumo* to a dog gnawing a bone. *Mikuno* is nicknamed "four eyes" since he wears glasses which immediately labels him as having low trion.  *Ninomiya* is a superior fighter to *Mikumo* and his quote is  criticizing *Mikumo* as a "light weight" fighter.

*Ninomiya* is basically saying that *Mikumo* will never have a fulfilling "mouthful of strategy" but only "bits and pieces of tactics" for his fighting ability.  It also plays into the image of "giving a dog a bone" to keep them quiet while they are preoccupied "gnawing on the bone".